# How to normalise multiple arrays?

Tags: python

I'm trying to normalize numbers within multiple arrays. I have 10 arrays with 5 numbers each. I have been able to normalize my first array, but all other arrays take the parameters from the first array. my code norm func:

```
normfeatures = (features - np.min (features)) / (np.max(features) - np.min(features))
```

how can I make it so that each array takes the min and max from their own array rather than the min and max from the first one?

Comment: Try using this http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html

Answer (score 0):

You could always use sklearn's `Normalizer`, but if you want to do it with numpy

```
import numpy as np

#Same size
X = np.random.randint(-5,5,size = (10,5))


mins = X.min(axis = 1)
maxs = X.max(axis = 1)

X_normalized = (X - mins[:,None])/(maxs[:,None] - mins[:, None])
```

This will normalize by rows.  If you want to normalize by columns, you can first transpose your data and then apply this procedure before transposing back.  Or, you can just use sklearn's implementation.